# Aligning a set of equations

Tags: align

I'm currently writing a dissertation using Texmaker and I'm fairly new to it! I have a set of three equations that I want to align so that they all start underneath each other on the left.

I have tried this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

    $$\begin{aligned} \rho = \int_{2MG}^r \sqrt{g_{rr}(r')} dr' \\
    =  \int_{2MG}^{r} (1-\dfrac{2MG}{r'})^{-0.5} dr' \\
    = \sqrt{r(r-2MG)}+2MGsinh^{-1} (\sqrt{\dfrac{r}{2MG}-1)}\end{aligned}$$
\end{document}
```

It doesn't seem to work as I want it!

Can anyone please offer me some words of wisdom?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Also, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with equation numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\rho &= \int_{2MG}^r \sqrt{g_{rr}(r')} dr' \\ 
       &= \int_{2MG}^{r} (1-\dfrac{2MG}{r'})^{-0.5} dr' \\ 
       &= \sqrt{r(r-2MG)}+2MG\sinh^{-1} (\sqrt{\dfrac{r}{2MG}-1)}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without equation numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\rho &= \int_{2MG}^r \sqrt{g_{rr}(r')} dr' \\ 
       &= \int_{2MG}^{r} (1-\dfrac{2MG}{r'})^{-0.5} dr' \\ 
       &= \sqrt{r(r-2MG)}+2MG\sinh^{-1} (\sqrt{\dfrac{r}{2MG}-1)}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh that works brilliantly thank you! How do I get rid of the numbers that appear on the right hand side?

Comment: Use `\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}` ...

Comment: Also, use `\sinh` in your equation.

Answer (score 4):

Since yours is a single equation, it is always better to use the combination `equation`-`split` instead of `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Numbered equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\rho &= \int_{2MG}^r \sqrt{g_{rr}(r')}\,dr' \\
       &= \int_{2MG}^{r} \biggl(1-\dfrac{2MG}{r'}\biggr)^{\!-0.5} dr' \\
       &= \sqrt{r(r-2MG)}+2MG\sinh^{-1} \biggl(\sqrt{\dfrac{r}{2MG}-1}\,\biggr)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\bigskip
\textbf{Unnumbered equation}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\rho &= \int_{2MG}^r \sqrt{g_{rr}(r')}\,dr' \\
       &= \int_{2MG}^{r} \biggl(1-\dfrac{2MG}{r'}\biggr)^{\!-0.5} dr' \\
       &= \sqrt{r(r-2MG)}+2MG\sinh^{-1} \biggl(\sqrt{\dfrac{r}{2MG}-1}\,\biggr)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've also added some `\biggl(`-`\biggr)` to have better looking parenthesis and added some (positive and negative) spacing around.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\differential[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
  \rho
  &= \int_{2MG}^{r} \sqrt{g_{rr}(r')} \differential{r'}\\
  &= \int_{2MG}^{r} {\mkern -5mu}\left(1 - \frac{2MG}{r'}\right)^{\mkern -4mu -0.5} \differential{r'}\\
  &= \sqrt{r(r - 2MG)} + 2MG\sinh^{-1}{\mkern -8mu}\left(\sqrt{\frac{r}{2MG}} - 1\right){\mkern -5mu}.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comments:

- There is no need for loading the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package in this case.
- Use, say, `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$` for highlighted math expressions.
- There is no need for both `$$` (which you shouldn't use at all) and `aligned`; you are declaring a math environment inside a math environment.
- Notice the use of the combination of `split` inside `equation*` instead of `aligned` in order to get a single, vertically centered number for the equation block.
- There is no need for `\dfrac` here; `\frac` will suffice.
- I have used `\left(`/`\right)` in order to automatically scale the parentheses.
- I've added negative space around `\left(`/`\right)` (via `\mkern`) in order to get a better horizontal spacing.
- Use the macro `\sinh` instead of just typing `sinh`; it is a math operator.
- I have defined the macro `\differential` for the differential. (To quote Basil Fawlty from Fawlty Towers: "[...] Special subject: The bleedin' obvious".)